# Sorting option between grid and list view

Tags: tables, grid, sort, listview

I have a view in our saas product which has a grid of items as cards. In the toolbar there is a dropdown for sorting which one of the options being 'most recent' - this is the most common sorting option for this view. We are introducing a way to see the same grid components as a list due to the amount of items being in this view now. Problem Im having is we'll be removing the sorting dropdown in this view as the columns themselves would be sortable, all good so far. Issue arises is that the product manager doesn't want to have a column for 'last accessed' so that the same 'most recent' sorting option can be replicated in this view as it he believes its too much data and cognitive overload.

What is everyone's thoughts on this, I think it this is the best and most understandable way to view this data and will argue this. Does anyone else have any other suggestions on how to tackle this besides what I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Windows Explorer, they have a dedicated sort button in addition to the column sorting, and the sorting options don't necessarily have to be represented as columns in the view.

Looking at Google Docs, the recently opened documents list doesn't even have column headers which can sort the entries, but rather have a dedicated sort button. The sorting button then also immediately changes the date column between last opened/last changed, such that you aren't overloaded with data.

Your answer probably would be one of those patterns. Given that you've taught your users that there's a sorting button, keeping the button offers better consistency and affordance.